# onEdit function update undo history

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to store the last modification user and date of a sheet in developer metadata.

I use the onEdit function to update these metadata at each edit of a sheet (please see the code below)

My problem is the metadata creation/update is taken into account in the undo history.

So users need to ctrl+Z three times for one cancel...

Do you know a way to avoid this behavior?

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  // Prevent errors if no object is passed.
  if (!e) return;

  var dateMetadata;
  var dateKey = 'lastModificationDate';
  var userMetadata;
  var userKey = 'lastModificationUser';

  // Get the active sheet.
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var user = e.user.getEmail();
  var date = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  metadatas = sheet.getDeveloperMetadata();

  for each (var m in metadatas) {
    if (m.getKey() === dateKey) {
      dateMetadata = m;
    }

    if (m.getKey() === userKey) {
      userMetadata = m;
    }
  }

  if (dateMetadata) {
    dateMetadata.setValue(date);
  } else {
    sheet.addDeveloperMetadata(dateKey, date);
  }

  if (userMetadata) {
    userMetadata.setValue(user);
  } else {
    sheet.addDeveloperMetadata(userKey, user);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- After the script was run, when one time "ctrl+Z" is pushed, you want to undo the put value.

  - In your current script, after a value is put to a cell, the undo can be done by pushing 3 times "ctrl+Z".

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Modification points:

- When the Spreadsheet is opened from outside and modify the Spreadsheet with the script, even when "ctrl+Z" is pushed, the undo cannot be done. In your case, I thought that this can be used.

  - Use `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(sheetName)` instead of `var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()`.

### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it become as follows.

#### From:

```
function onEdit(e) {
```

#### To:

```
function installedOnEdit(e) {
```

In this case, [please install the installable OnEdit event trigger for the function of `installedOnEdit`.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) By this, `openById` can be used.

And also, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
```

#### To:

```
var id = e.source.getId();
var sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(sheetName);
```

### Note:

- When the installable OnEdit event trigger is used, the double run of functions can be prevented by changing the function name from `onEdit` to `installedOnEdit`. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/88f7fd5ed14da5e9afde18310da61cb5)
- In this case, unfortunately, it cannot confirm using the event object whether "ctrl+Z" was pushed. By this, the added developer metadata cannot be canceled with "ctrl+Z". Please be careful this.
- As another method, of course, I think that you can also use Sheets API in your situation.

### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Asynchronous Processing using Event Triggers](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/88f7fd5ed14da5e9afde18310da61cb5)
- [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)
- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html#getSheetByName(String))

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @eli0tt Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: I just implemented your To: From: stragegy and BAM!: now besides updating my sheet on the onEdit() trigger, my users recovered the ability to do undos also! Thanks!

Comment: @Zecas Thank you for your comment. I'm glad for it. Thank you, too.